# How to do a Left Join in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, gridview

I'm new to LINQ and EF.. I have a method that is used to set the datasource of a gridView.

```
public static List<PolicyLimit> GetAll(int policyID, int limitType) {
        List<PolicyLimit> limits = null;

        limits = (from x in DbContextHelper.DbContext.PolicyLimit.Include("Limit")
                  //.Include("ClaimLimit")

                  join s in DbContextHelper.DbContext.ClaimLimit on x.PolicyID equals s.PolicyID into abc
                  from subabc in abc.DefaultIfEmpty()


                  where x.PolicyID == policyID 
                  select  x ).Take(100).ToList<PolicyLimit>();

        return limits;
    }
```

This method works fine without the join that I put in place.  I have 3 new columns I added to my grid, these are columns are found in this 3rd table I'm trying to join.

I added a 'PolicyID' field to the 3rd table to link it to my main table 'PolicyLimit'.  Keep in mind this method was already created.  I just want to include the value from the 3rd table to bind my new columns.

Currently since the 2nd table is linked using INCLUDE, in my gridview code I just have

```
<asp:Label ID="txtDescription" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Bind("Limit.LimitDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
```

I want to be able to do the same with the ClaimLimit table..Bind("ClaimLimit.CloumnName")

I've tried creating an association in the Model Diagram but that was unsuccessful, so I'm trying to just do a LEFT join in my LINQ but when I change my select to

```
select new{x, subabc.SomeColumn}).Take(100).ToList<PolicyLimit>();
```

It complains about that...  not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What errors are you getting, what do you mean by "creating an association in the Model Diagram but that was unsuccessful", unsuccessful how?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: x is a `PolicyLimit`, so why would you expect that you can cram a tuple of {x, subabc.SomeColumn} into a same `PolicyLimit`? (Your list still contains PolicyLimits, not {PolicyLimit, SomeColumn}.

Comment: @BenRobinson The "Limit" table I have is connected through a FK association (1 to many).  I tried to do the same for the new table on the ID column I added but it was complaining about mapping hadn't been established.

Comment: @oerkelens So how should I go about getting the values from the joined table?

Comment: @Omar, you can get the values but you will not have a `List<PolicyLimit>` you will have a List of the anonymous type produced by your `select new{x, subabc.SomeColumn})`